# Adding values of different sizes in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day everyone,
     I am hoping someone could help me with an issue I am having. I have a database that stores the amount of data that was reviewed on a hard drive. The values can either be Megabytes or Gigabytes.

Example:

```
Hard Drive 1       100MB
Hard Drive 2       2.5 GB
Hard Drive 3       650 MB
```

My question is this. I need to add these values up to get a total amount of data that was reviewed. I need to convert the Megabytes to Gigabytes and then add all the values together to get a total.

Can I do this in a query, or would a function be better for something like this?  And how would I go about doing this?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Where do you get these data from (db, flat file...) ? How are they formatted ?

Comment: It would be easier if the units were in a separate field, but a little string manipulation can split them if necessary.  Once you have them separated you can use a CASE statement to multiply them by the correct amount to then compare them.

Comment: I assume the data (100MB, 2.5GB, 650MB) are varchars or something similar?

Comment: Actually they are stored as decimal(18,3)

Comment: Are the 'MB' and 'GB' values in a separate column?

Comment: Can you please post the "create table" statement?

Comment: You can't store '100MB' in a `decimal(18,3)`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  the '100' in '100MB' is stored in a column.  the 'MB' is stored in another column, so they are stored in seperate columns.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to get the size by `CASE` like

```
Size / 
    CASE Unit 
        WHEN 'KB' THEN 1000 * 1000 
        WHEN 'MB' THEN 1000 
        WHEN 'GB' THEN 1 
        WHEN 'TB' THEN 0.001 
    END
```

Example for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Table table
(
    Size decimal(18,3),
    Unit char(2)
)

INSERT @Table VALUES (100, 'MB'), (2.5, 'GB'), (650, 'MB')

-- Get size for all rows
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONVERT(decimal(18, 3), 
        Size / CASE Unit WHEN 'MB' THEN 1000 WHEN 'GB' THEN 1 END
    ) AS GB 
FROM @Table

-- Get total
SELECT       
    CONVERT(decimal(18, 3), SUM(
        Size / CASE Unit WHEN 'MB' THEN 1000 WHEN 'GB' THEN 1 END
    )) AS GB 
FROM @Table
```

Result

```
Size                                    Unit GB
--------------------------------------- ---- ---------------------------------------
100.000                                 MB   0.01
2.500                                   GB   2.500
650.000                                 MB   0.650

(3 row(s) affected)

TotalGB
---------------------------------------
3.250

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement for this.

`SELECT
    CASE WHEN COL3 LIKE '%MB' THEN COL2 * 1024
    WHEN COL3 LIKE '%GB' THEN COL2 * 100 END AS "SIZE" --x100 to get decimal right
FROM...`

Answer (score 0):

If your schema defines the size and the 'unit multiplier' in *separate columns*, like this:

```
create table disks  (
  id int not null, 
  size varchar(20) not null,
  mult_id varchar(2)
)
go
```

Then create a table to map each string quantifier to the size (in MB)

```
create table mult  (
  id varchar(2) not null, 
  mult int not null
)
go


insert into disks(id, size, mult_id) values 
  (1, 200, 'GB'),
  (2, 100, 'MB'),
  (3, 200, 'TB')

insert into mult(id, mult) values 
  ('MB', 1),
  ('GB', 1000),
  ('TB', 1000000)
```

This will give the size of each disk in MB

```
-- The SELECT to get the result of each disk in MB
SELECT disks.id, size * mult.mult size_mb FROM disks JOIN mult on disks.mult_id = mult.id
```

You can add other multipliers as required to the 'mult' table